# Like DOjo Does Jquery has got its own components for development

Tags: jquery

a very good day to all of you .

I am trying to  compare DOJO and JQuery .
What i observed is that , DOJO is very vast ( In package size ) and jquery isn't that much big at all.

DOJO provides its own components for every HTML component .

For example for a normal TextFiled

The DOJo form is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
</script>
```

Does Jquery also provides its own components ?? , Because when i googled , i didn't came  across any such .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out jqueryUI

http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Thank you very much , is this officially from Jquery developers itself ??